# How to use os.system to convert all files in a folder at once using external python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I've managed to find out the method to convert a file from one file extension to another (.evtx to .xml) using an external script. Below is what I am using:

```
os.system("file_converter.py file1.evtx > file1.xml")
```

This successfully converts a file from .txt to .xml using the external script I called (file_converter.py).

I am now trying to find out a method on how I can use 'os.system' or perhaps another method to convert more than one file at once, I would like for my program to dive into a folder and convert all of the 10 files I have at once to .xml format.

The questions I have are how is this possible as os.system only takes 1 argument and I'm not sure on how I could make it locate through a directory as unlike the first file I converted was on my standard home directory, but the folder I want to access with the 10 files is inside of another folder, I am trying to find out a way to address this argument and for the conversion to be done at once, I also want the file name to stay the same for each individual file with the only difference being the '.xml' being changed from '.evtx' at the end.

The file "file_converter.py" is downloadable from [here](https://github.com/williballenthin/python-evtx/blob/master/scripts/evtx_dump.py)

Comment: There are many ways. Your external script file_converter could do it if you modify it (directory_converter) or the other script that calls this script could do it by calling it repeatedly. At some point a loop will be necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import threading
import os

def file_converter(file):
    os.system("file_converter.py {0} > {1}".format(file, file.replace(".evtx", ".xml")))

base_dir = "C:\\Users\\carlo.zanocco\\Desktop\\test_dir\\"

for file in os.listdir(base_dir):
    threading.Thread(target=file_converter, args=(file,)).start()
```

Here my sample code.
You can generate multiple thread to run the operation "concurrently". The program will check for all files in the directory and convert it.

### EDIT python2.7 version

Now that we have more information about what you want I can help you.
This program can handle multiple file concurrently from one folder, it check also into the subfolders.

```
import subprocess
import os

base_dir = "C:\\Users\\carlo.zanocco\\Desktop\\test_dir\\"
commands_to_run = list()

#Search all files 
def file_list(directory):
    allFiles = list()
    for entry in os.listdir(directory):
        fullPath = os.path.join(directory, entry)
        #if is directory search for more files
        if os.path.isdir(fullPath):
            allFiles = allFiles + file_list(fullPath)
        else:
            #check that the file have the right extension and append the command to execute later
            if(entry.endswith(".evtx")):
                commands_to_run.append("C:\\Python27\\python.exe file_converter.py {0} > {1}".format(fullPath, fullPath.replace(".evtx", ".xml")))

    return allFiles

print "Searching for files"
file_list(base_dir)
print "Running conversion"
processes = [subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True) for command in commands_to_run]
print "Waiting for converted files"
for process in processes:
    process.wait()
print "Conversion done"
```

The subprocess module can be used in two ways:

1. subprocess.Popen: it run the process and continue the execution
2. subprocess.call: it run the process and wait for it, this function return the exit status. This value if zero indicate that the process terminate succesfully

### EDIT python3.7 version

if you want to solve all your problem just implement the code that you share from github in your program. You can easily implement it as function.

```
import threading
import os

import Evtx.Evtx as evtx
import Evtx.Views as e_views

base_dir = "C:\\Users\\carlo.zanocco\\Desktop\\test_dir\\"

def convert(file_in, file_out):
    tmp_list = list()
    with evtx.Evtx(file_in) as log:
        tmp_list.append(e_views.XML_HEADER)
        tmp_list.append("<Events>")
        for record in log.records():
            try:
                tmp_list.append(record.xml())
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
        tmp_list.append("</Events>")

    with open(file_out, 'w') as final:
        final.writelines(tmp_list)

#Search all files 
def file_list(directory):
    allFiles = list()
    for entry in os.listdir(directory):
        fullPath = os.path.join(directory, entry)
        #if is directory search for more files
        if os.path.isdir(fullPath):
            allFiles = allFiles + file_list(fullPath)
        else:
            #check that the file have the right extension and append the command to execute later
            if(entry.endswith(".evtx")):
                threading.Thread(target=convert, args=(fullPath, fullPath.replace(".evtx", ".xml"))).start()

    return allFiles

print("Searching and converting files")
file_list(base_dir)
```

If you want to show your files generate, just edit as above:

```
def convert(file_in, file_out):
    tmp_list = list()
    with evtx.Evtx(file_in) as log:
        with open(file_out, 'a') as final:
            final.write(e_views.XML_HEADER)
            final.write("<Events>")
            for record in log.records():
                try:
                    final.write(record.xml())
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
            final.write("</Events>")
```

### UPDATE

If you want to delete the '.evtx' files after the conversion you can simply add the following rows at the end of the `convert` function:

```
try:
    os.remove(file_in)
except(Exception, ex):
    raise ex
```

Here you just need to use `try .. except` because you run the thread only if the input value is a file.
If the file doesn't exist, this function throws an exception, so it's necessary to check `os.path.isfile()` first.

Comment: Note that ```os.system``` is now deprecated. Spawning a new thread for every file is also a bad idea, and will not speed the process it.

Comment: Just for comparison. Using your threaded solution on five files took ```0.2``` seconds on my HDD where as my non threaded solution took ```0.0```.

Comment: You are right that he should be more clear, he simply wrote ```convert a file from one file extension to another``` :)

Comment: @Carlo Zanocco Thanks very much for your help, I have attempted to implement this code for my program but I'm having some problems, for the command: commands_to_run.append("C:\\Python27\\python.exe file_converter.py {0} > {1}".format(fullPath, fullPath.replace(".evtx", ".xml")))                                              I am currently running Python3.7 and can't find .exe in directory, am unsure what to include, when I run the program, I get'ValueError: cannot mmap an empty file'. The script I want to use: https://github.com/williballenthin/python-evtx/blob/master/scripts/evtx_dump.py

Comment: You have to change "C:\\Python27\\python.exe" with the directory of your python3.7 installation folder. About the "ValueError" problem Can you show me your directory trees?

Comment: @CarloZanocco I have changed the directory to "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ evtx_dump.py" does the dump file have to be inside of this folder as it's currently in another folder in my user area. For my directory tree, I have a 'test' folder in my user area which I just made to include a couple evtx files, which I have included in the base_dir section. With changing the path, I no longer get the 'ValueError' but I do happen to get a 'Permission Denied' along with the new path I included.

Comment: `"C:\\Python27\\python.exe"` is the python installation directory. `file_converter.py` is the file downloaded from github. The .evtx files directory is the variable called base_dir. So the program checks into the base_dir for the files, and run the subprocess in function of your python installation directory, the program downloaded from github with the arguments required. I think that on linux you dont need to specify the python directory if you have python inserted in your environament variables.

Comment: Your `base_dir = "/my/evtx/files/directory/"`.
The command for subprocess.Popen()  `/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ evtx_dump.py {0} > {1}"`

The file `evtx_dump.py` must be in the same directory of your program directory

Comment: @CarloZanocco I have changed everything so it should be running fine but when I check my folder of my base_dir instead of converting the file it is deleting all data from the files and showing 0bytes for each file.

Comment: Deleting all I think is not possibile, there is no delete command in my program. The 0 bytes files means that the subprocess.Popen can't find python.exe.

Comment: I have converted the code on my pc for python3.7. That means, use print as function, so add the '(' and ')', and changed the command into: `commands_to_run.append(r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe"' + " file_converter.py {0} > {1}".format(fullPath, fullPath.replace(".evtx", ".xml")))`

It is working fine, it generate all the files as .xml with all the bytes.

Can you tell me which version of linux are you running, with specific python version and IDE? So I can test it in your environement

Comment: @CarloZanocco I am attempting to use the Python3.7 code you included above and when I run the program it displays 'Searching and converting files' in the terminal, when I check the folder it has converted most of them except from two for some reason. Also when I attempt to work through multiple sub directories with files inside of them I get an error in the terminal displaying 'SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal' is this because the base_dir only allows a specific folder and not a directory which contains multiple folders? I am currently running Linux Mint 5, Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @CarloZanocco Sorry my mistake, it is converting them and now working perfectly, thank you so much! I have realized it is keeping the original .evtx files as well, is there a way I can make an edit just do display the newly converted files in the folder?

Comment: What do you mean? Print in the terminal the newly created file directory? or delete the .evtx files and keep just the .xml? Remember to mark the answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it is right.

Comment: @CarloZanocco When I locate the directory after conversion has been completed, I see the newly converted .xml files but the original .evtx files remain, I was wondering what the best way would be on how the program could delete them after conversion, would it be the simplest to just use os.remove at the end? I shall mark the answer as accepted, you have been extremely useful, thanks very much!

Comment: Yes, you can use `os.remove()`. You just need to add to the end of the `convert` function the rows in the updated post.

Comment: @CarloZanocco All functioning. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
import os, sys

DIR = "D:/Test"

# ...or as a command line argument

DIR = sys.argv[1]

for f in os.listdir(DIR):
    path = os.path.join(DIR, f)

    name, ext = os.path.splitext(f)

    if ext == ".txt":
        new_path = os.path.join(DIR, f"{name}.xml")    

        os.rename(path, new_path)
```

Iterates over a directory, and changes all text files to XML.

Comment: Thanks very much. However, this only changes the extension to XML but when I try to open the newly converted XML file it is corrupted as it doesn't utilize my 'converter.py' script which converts the extension, I'm trying to find out a way on how I could implement this script into this?

Comment: You need to be more clear and show us the script if you want us to be able to efficiently help you.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but I made a mistake in my original post, I'm trying to utilise this script to convert from .evtx to .xml: https://github.com/williballenthin/python-evtx/blob/master/scripts/evtx_dump.py